# PHP API Reflection

Tags: php, c, php-internals

I want to find where such messages are generated at a low level.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to A::__construct() must be an instance of B
```

I downloaded the source PHP 7. And tried to find the formation of an error pattern "must be an instance"

Me interests where arguments of the __construct  parsed in php.

Comment: Question, do you have it?

Comment: Yes, where is this exception thrown?